# Load XML file with different element

Tags: c#, xml

I am currently working on a load an XML file with different elements inside.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Users>
    <User>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <FirstName>Test</FirstName>
        <LastName>1</LastName>
        <Email>test@hotmail.com</Email>
        <Password>123</Password>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <AccountType>Admin</AccountType>
      </User>
      <Patient>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <FirstName>Test</FirstName>
        <LastName>2</LastName>
        <Email>test123@hotmail.com</Email>
        <Phone>12345678</Phone>
        <Password>123</Password>
        <DateOfBirth>3/12/1994</DateOfBirth>
        <Address>Testing 1</Address>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <BloodGroup>B+</BloodGroup>
        <AccountType>Patient</AccountType>
      </Patient>
</Users>
```

User.cs

```
public static List<Users> LoadUser;
```

Patient.cs

```
public static List<Patient> LoadPatient;
```

How do I load an XML file with the different elements inside into two different lists without using de-serialize?

Like the user element will be saved at the `LoadUser` and the patient element will be saved at the `LoadPatient`?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution for the *User*.

The *Patient* part would be identical.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    const string filePath = @"e:\Temp\AllenWalker.xml";
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filePath);

    List<User> Users = xdoc.Descendants("User").Select(val => new User()
    {
        ID = val.Elements("ID").FirstOrDefault().Value,
        FirstName = val.Elements("FirstName").FirstOrDefault().Value,
        LastName = val.Elements("LastName").FirstOrDefault().Value,
        Email = val.Elements("Email").FirstOrDefault().Value,
        Password = val.Elements("Password").FirstOrDefault().Value,
        Gender = val.Elements("Gender").FirstOrDefault().Value,
        AccountType = val.Elements("AccountType").FirstOrDefault().Value
    }).ToList();
}

public class User
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string AccountType { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement xUser = doc.Descendants("User").FirstOrDefault();
            User user = new User();
            user.id = (int)xUser.Element("ID");
            user.firstname = (string)xUser.Element("FirstName");
            user.lastname = (string)xUser.Element("LastName");
            user.email = (string)xUser.Element("Email");
            user.password = (string)xUser.Element("Password");
            user.gender = (string)xUser.Element("Gender");
            user.accountType = (string)xUser.Element("AccountType");

            XElement xPatient = doc.Descendants("Patient").FirstOrDefault();
            Patient patient = new Patient();
            patient.id = (int)xPatient.Element("ID");
            patient.firstname = (string)xPatient.Element("FirstName");
            patient.lastname = (string)xPatient.Element("LastName");
            patient.email = (string)xPatient.Element("Email");
            patient.phone = (string)xPatient.Element("Phone");
            patient.password = (string)xPatient.Element("Password");
            patient.dob = (DateTime)xPatient.Element("DateOfBirth");
            patient.address = (string)xPatient.Element("Address");
            patient.gender = (string)xPatient.Element("Gender");
            patient.bloodGroup = (string)xPatient.Element("BloodGroup");
            patient.accountType = (string)xPatient.Element("AccountType");
        }
    }
    public class User
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string firstname { get; set; }
        public string lastname { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public string gender { get; set; }
        public string accountType { get; set; }
    }
    public class Patient
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string firstname { get; set; }
        public string lastname { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public DateTime dob { get; set; }
        public string  address { get; set; }
        public string gender { get; set; }
        public string bloodGroup { get; set; }
        public string accountType { get; set; }
    }
}
```